# EMC VNXe and Windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, emc-vnxe

I am having a hard time finding anything related to support ability with my EMC VNXe 3100 and Windows Server 2012. I am planning on going to Hyper-V 2012 and moving my file shares to Windows Server 2012 as opposed to the file server on the VNXe. Does anyone have any information with integration with these products?

UPDATE!! RTM just announced first week of August. Maybe more info will surface.

Comment: Which specific compatibility issues are you thinking of? Could you explain what sort of integration are you planning? When u say ``integration'', do you mean replacing one with another or serving hyper-v volumes from vnxe.

Comment: I was specifically looking for SCVMM being able to manage volumes on the VNXe, the current inability to map a network drive from the VNXe, and the new features that Server 2012 have for backend storage collaboration.

Answer (score 2):

From what I could find from EMC employees is that there is no "official" information yet.

[image]